# Как убрать заданное количество повторяющихся символов в строке?

Tags: kotlin

Есть строка вида

```
val bits = "11001100110011000000..."
```

Как из такой строки  получить строку вида

```
"1010101000"
```

Т.е. в данном примере каждое "слово" состоит из двух символов. Как уменьшить количество символов?

Comment: хорошо сформулировано для запроса в браузере, но не для вопроса на этом сайте.

Comment: т.е. идеальный ответ будет 10?

Comment: В заданной строке видно, что длина одного "слова" составляет 2 символа. Вот как каждую пару превратить в один символ? 11 в 1, 00 в 0. При этом нет необходимости делать это до конца. Нужно просто сделать 1 проход по заданной строке и превратить все пары в единичные символы.

Comment: А если будет 111000?

Comment: Тогда "слово" будет состоять из трёх символов и результат будет 0. Но пока вопрос стоит именно так, как условие выше. Считаем, что все строки смогут пройти преобразование.

Comment: Вы не можете пройти по строке или не можете заменить два на один?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val res = bits.slice(0 until bits.length step 2)
```

Comment: Кстати, да. Если все строки гарантировано могут пройти преобразование, то не надо и мудрить :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант самый простой и очевидный:

```
fun main() {
    val bits = "11001100110011000000"
    var newbits = ""
    for (index in 0..bits.length - 2 step 2) {
        // берем по два символа, сравниваем и создаем новую строку
        val sym = when (bits.subSequence(index, index + 2)) {
            "11" -> "1"
            "00" -> "0"
            else -> ""
        }
        newbits = newbits + sym
    }
    println(newbits) // 1010101000
}
```

Можно воспользоваться методом [windowed()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/windowed.html):

```
for (word in bits.windowed(2, 2)) { // подстроки длиной 2 с шагом 2
    newbits = newbits + when (word) {
        "11" -> "1"
        "00" -> "0"
        else -> ""
    }
}
println(newbits) // 1010101000
```